# Store key value in Java

Tags: java

I have a case in which I need to store huge numbers into key and value.
I tried:

```
HashMap<String, double> map = new HashMap<String, double>();
map.put("Type1", 1267650600228229401496703205376);
```

I get syntax error. Is there a way to store key and value with huge number?

Comment: How about `BigDecimal` or `BigInteger`

Comment: If you're storing that big of a number, could you use a String instead?

Comment: You cannot use a primitive as a generic type for the map. Also, the number as you write it is interpreted as an int but is too big to fit in an int.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
HashMap<String, Double> map1 = new HashMap<String, Double>();
map1.put("Type1", 1267650600228229401496703205376D);
```

or

```
HashMap<String, BigDecimal> map2 = new HashMap<String, BigDecimal>();
map2.put("Type1", new BigDecimal("1267650600228229401496703205376"));
```

Comment: I tried with Double but I need to cast the numbers every time The method put(String, Double) in the type HashMap<String,Double> is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)

Comment: Using a `Double` to hold really big integers is a really bad idea. If you find yourself switching to double because long long was too small, you're doing something wrong

Comment: @Fureeish OP said huge numbers, didn't specify they were integers. Also, his example shows doubles... I agree, of course, if those are integers use `Long` and/or `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 0):

Please read about `BigDecimal`
It works with big double values and supports needed for you accuracy.
Also you can use `BigInteger` for integer values.

There are so many method for working with big values, also `compareTo()` for comparing.

Answer (score 0):

Use BitInteger if your numbers won't be insanely large like your example, or just store it as a String.

```
HashMap<String, BitInteger> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Type1", BigInteger.valueOf(12676506));
```